# Python requests throws Connection Broken: ChunkedEncodingError with http.client.IncompleteRead when trying to download a file

Tags: python, curl, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, wget

I'm trying to download a PDF file using the requests module, the code is as below:

```
import requests

url = "<url of the pdf>"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=(60, 120), headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136'})

print(r.headers)
print(r.status_code)

try:
    with open('blah.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r:
            # print(chunk)
            f.write(chunk)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Output is given below:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Wed, 02 Oct 2019 05:17:11 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': 'bbb=rd102o00000000000000000000ffff978433aao80; path=/; Httponly; Secure'}
200
('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected))
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 755, in read_chunked
    chunk = self._handle_chunk(amt)
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 709, in _handle_chunk
    self._fp._safe_read(2)  # Toss the CRLF at the end of the chunk.
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 612, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(s), amt)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 560, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    for chunk in r:
  File "/storage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2 more expected))
```

When I open that pdf on Web Browsers such as Google Chrome, chrome's builtin pdf plugin can load it properly and it is possible to read on the browser. However, If I try to download it by clicking on the download icon I get `Failed - Network Error` Firefox can't load/download it. (Both Firefox & Chrome are upgraded to latest version) When I test it on a windows machine Microsoft edge was able to download the pdf though...

The above code, If I test it with some other pdfs such as this one:
https://adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/accessibility/products/acrobat/pdfs/acrobat-x-accessibility-checker.pdf
It works perfectly.

I've tried some command-line tools such as curl, wget, aria2c (with proper headers set like browser request) all failed to download the pdf.

wget output:

```
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘blah.pdf’

<pdf_url>     [      <=>                          ] 101.68K  66.1KB/s    in 1.5s    

2019-10-02 11:29:50 (69.1 KB/s) - Read error at byte 108786 (Success).
```

The file downloaded using `wget` is corrupted.

Another thing that I've tried is to inspect it using mitm and chromedriver+selenium combination.

The automated chrome browser can't load the pdf and shows an error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
HttpSyntaxException('Malformed chunked body',)
```

How can I download this pdf using `requests` module? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue after a couple of days. The server was closing the connection improperly so, the python libraries were throwing `IncompleteReadError`. I managed to download it using the `curl` installed in the system with the argument `--compressed` and all the necessary headers:

```
from subprocess import call

pdf_url = ""
pdf_filename = ""
call(["curl", pdf_url, 
    '-H', 'Connection: keep-alive', 
    '-H', 'Cache-Control: max-age=0', 
    '-H', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1', 
    '-H', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36', 
    '-H', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate', 
    '-H', 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3', 
    '-H', 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site', 
    '-H', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br', 
    '-H', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8', 
    '-H', 'Cookie: bbb=rd102o00000000000000000000ffff978432aao80', 
    '--compressed', '--output', pdf_filename])
```

Using the [call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) method of the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Even though curl shows an error message like below:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

But, the downloaded pdf works and can be opened with any pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, I do not know the answer in why it happened it just did. I made this workaround with urrlib:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'foo_file.txt', data=your_queries)
```

What urlretrieve method does is fetch the data from the link and make a copy of it in the file name you specify and the path you specify as second argument. You can also change the type to .pdf, .json, whatever.

You have more info here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request

Comment: doesn't work same error as requests i.e. `http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(2290 bytes read)
`