Trouble with downloading a zip file with incomplete read
I'm having trouble downloading this zip file from the URL: https://www.dgii.gov.do/app/WebApps/Consultas/RNC/DGII_RNC.zip with python code.
I tried many things but every time I try to download the zip the file seems to be corrupted and doesn't have the whole content.
The only way I can download it is by manually entering the URL in a web browser.
One of the errors I ran into consistently:

requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken:
IncompleteRead(8388608 bytes read, 12299532 more expected)',
IncompleteRead(8388608 bytes read, 12299532 more expected))

import wget

wget.download('https://www.dgii.gov.do/app/WebApps/Consultas/RNC/DGII_RNC.zip')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marko-anchev/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    wget.download('https://www.dgii.gov.do/app/WebApps/Consultas/RNC/DGII_RNC.zip')
  File "/home/marko-anchev/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 276, in urlretrieve
    raise ContentTooShortError(
urllib.error.ContentTooShortError: <urlopen error retrieval incomplete: got only 8388608 out of 20696791 bytes>

Thank you in advance.

Question must provide a [mcve] so the URL to the file is not enough. Besides, that's a goverment site that might be protected.

Another option is to run something like wget or curl via the subprocess module.

@tdelaney I tried both, but I'm still ruining into the same or similar issue.

They both failed for me too. Maybe a bad server or corrupt file. Since those utilities don't work, this isn't going to be an obvious pilot error on your part.

@tdelaney I'm a bit confused as to why I'm not having troubles downloading it properly by click on the download link on this URL: https://www.dgii.gov.do/app/WebApps/ConsultasWeb/consultas/rnc.aspx. But when I try directly with different approaches using Python I wasn't able to.

Did you try with requests library instead of wget? requests.get(url) ...

@rehaqds
import requests
url = 'https://www.dgii.gov.do/app/WebApps/Consultas/RNC/DGII_RNC.zip'
local_filename = 'DGII_RNC.zip'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
print(response.content)
Yes when I try to get the content like this, I get the following error:
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(8388608 bytes read, 12308183 more expected)', IncompleteRead(8388608 bytes read, 12308183 more expected))

Looks like the problem comes from the server. Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195791/python-requests-throws-connection-broken-chunkedencodingerror-with-http-client

Worked fine for me. Python 3.13.0, wget module version 3.2.

The error comes from the server after analyzing and seeing that even the pip: https://pypi.org/project/dgii-rnc has the same issue.
